# Spelling of Hanukkah

Tags: chanuka

The word Hanukkah in Hebrew is written חֲנֻכָּה or חֲנוּכָּה -- with or without a vav.  Why two spellings?  Do they entail different things?

(Delete the question if the answer is purely a grammatical matter and does not enhance our understanding of Judaism.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ktiv_hasar_niqqud

Comment: @DoubleAA -- So the vav is sometimes added to make sure the reader understands it is preceded by a (fairly rare) kubutz?

Comment: Those who expound חנו כה need that vav

Comment: @Maurice exactly. Same with מגילה vs [מגלה](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.36.27), and כתובה vs [כתבה](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30804/759) and many others

Comment: Does that mean you can add letters at will for clarity, or is this flexibility reserved for specific words?