# Is the phrase הקדוש ברוך הוא gramatically incorrect?

Tags: hebrew, shemos-sacred-names, prayer-book

Based on the answer to [this M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57942/is-there-a-difference-in-meaning-between-%D7%A7%D6%B8%D7%93%D6%B9%D6%BD%D7%A9%D7%81-and-%D7%A7%D6%B9%D6%BD%D7%93%D6%B6%D7%A9%D7%81), stating that קדוש is an adjective, wouldn't the expression  הקדוש ברוך הוא be grammatically incorrect? Shouldn't it be הקודש ברוך הוא , since קודש is a noun?

Have we been saying it incorrectly all along? The *Siddur* uses הקדוש ברוך הוא in many places (See end of יקום פורקן paragraphs as a sample.) Have we been doing this wrong for so many years? If the term is grammatically incorrect, how / why did this error begin, esp. in the Siddur?

Comment: I think this question could be strengthened by citing a source which discusses this or makes use of the alternate expression "HaQodesh Barukh Hu". Also, isn't this questioned more related to grammar than Judaism per se? Apologies, but -1 for now until a mod can clarify.

Comment: @Lee - 1) My question asks about a hypothetical usage of "HaQodesh Barukh Hu". I'm implying that it doesn't exist. I did cite a place where "HaKadosh Baruch Hu" exists. 2), as you can see, I have accepted the answer given. Making this point, now, becomes a M.Y. technicality on whether a mod wants to close the question after an accepted answer - perhaps a point to place on meta. 3) Since I cited a spot, this is a grammar question related to Judaic usage & practice, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no source for this answer besides for my understanding of Hebrew.

I'm pretty sure that there's an implicit ([elliptical](http://grammar.about.com/od/e/g/ellipsisterm.htm) [h/t Yishai]) object here. We see this by the use of the definite article *ה*.

Also, notice how we translate it: *The Holy One Blessed Be He*. Here, *holy* is clearly an adjective, describing the object *one*. In Hebrew, the object is simply implicit.

הקודש would mean *the holiness*.

You can compare this form to הגדול -- *the big [one]*. Here to, there's an implicit object.

Comment: You need to strengthen your answer somewhat with a more reliable source. My Rav, who knows Hebrew very well, mentioned to me last week that he says "Hakodesh baruch hu", to the puzzled stares of surrounding people who hear him. Suggestion - see if you can locate other phrases where the definite article precedes an adj. and the noun is missing. I can't think of any, offhand.

Comment: I added a comparison as proof.

Comment: The technical term is an [elliptical](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/impersent09.htm) subject.

Comment: @DanF, I think that phrase states the quality of holiness to be the deity. I'm sure that wasn't his intent.

Comment: Ah! I had to think about where this is used on its own, and I think you refer to beginning of *Shemoneh Esreh*. Good example! I need to pass this onto my Rav, and get his resp0onse on this. Thanks! BTW "Shabbat Hagadol" does NOT mean "The great Shabbat", it means "The Shabbat OF the great (one). (I.e. - the Shabbat of the "rav" of the community.) Another example of the elliptical subject.

Comment: We also call HaShem "הגדול" "הגבור" and "הנורא". While another linguistic source could strength @Scimonster's answer, we have many examples in our tefillah referring to HaShem using these adjectives where the object is implicit (or elliptical).

Comment: @DanF I actually wasn't thinking of a specific source, just a Hebrew word. But good job finding a spot. :)

Comment: Also, note that this nickname for HaShem is used liberally throughout both Talmuds (Bavli and Yerushalmi) and the Mishneh Torah.

Comment: @Yishai actually, you reminded me about that part of the discussion I had with him last week. He DID mention the nuance in meaning that "Kodesh" means "Holiness" and, perhaps, his using that term WAS his intent. I have to "quiz" him a bit more.

Comment: "קודש" can also refer to "holy" (n.) as in "קודש הקודשים" (the Holy of Holies).

Comment: @Lee actually it can mean, "The *Holiness* of the Holies". I.e. within the Bet Hamikdash, the entire building is holy, but the inner sanctum has its unique "holiness".

Comment: Would "Qodesh HaQodashim" then be the "Holiness of the Holinesses"? :)

Comment: @Lee You're "teasing" me, here ;-) I have to check my Hebrew grammar, as my last translation could be wrong. I'll Cc DoubleAA. a good grammarian.   קדשים is the plural of which word - קודש or קדוש?

Comment: @DanF What are the vowels on קדשים?

Comment: @DoubleAA קָֽדָשִׁ֖ים