# What is the obligation of "Kedusha" (Holiness?)

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, kedusha-holiness, parashas-kedoshim

The verse in Leviticus (19:2) says "you shall be holy" what is the parameter of this and to what degree is it binding.

Rambam (Sefer Hamitzvos shoresh 4) writes that is is a general commandment to follow all the mitzvos.

Ramban explains the view of the Bahag that some commandments of kedusha do constitute individual mitzvos.

What are others' views on the scope of the commandment, and how binding it is (i.e. obligatory, praiseworthy, etc.)

Looking especially for the views of the Rishonim.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/what-does-kadosh-really-mean